# Java Game Programming: JOGL vs LWJGL?

Tags: java, graphics, jogl

I am currently writing a Turret Defense style game using the [GTGE engine](http://www.goldenstudios.or.id/products/GTGE/), this engine has the ability to use either JOGL or LWJGL to drive the graphics and so I was wondering, which one should I use? What are the pros/cons of each? What factors should I consider when deciding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my game development I had the following decision points:

- 2D or 3D game?
- How many time do I want to spent on development?
- How many control I want to practice over my rendering/game?
- How well can I model my game using an engine?
- What are my performance expectations?
- What kind of licensing will I release my game?

As I know, JOGL seems to be more in focus of Sun and other developers. I would expect bugfixes and enhancements more frequently.

If changing the driver does not require game/model changes, you could just benchmark both drivers. Then you could compare them based on memory consumption, rendering quality and speed.

Comment: Changing the driver would not require game/model changes, and so benchmarking is a great idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have used JOGL and my experience was preety good.
Also my reason for Opting JOGL was Sun backing.If both suits to your need then its better to go with widely accepted Api and at that time it was JOGL.