# Java real time strategy game development

Tags: java

I'm coming to the end of my first year of CS and I thought a great way to consolidate all the things I've learnt this year would be a personal game project.

I would like to implement a 2D based rts, I'm thinking along the lines of starcraft I, warcraft II or even command and conquer. I will have about 3 months without interruptions to implement the game.

So to anyone experienced with java game programming, I have a few questions:

Is it realistic to design a 2D rts engine from scratch in 3 months?
If so what are some good books/resources to get started?

Would it be better to modify some existing project? I would think the experience of having to work with a lot of someone else's code would be good since our exposure to such topics in an undergrad cs degree seems very rare, if non-existent.

Are there any decent open source 2d rts projects that anyone could recommend? I've looked through a few but most seem to be written in c/c++

My humble thanks

Edit: Thanks for the quick responses, I think that perhaps it was a bad idea to post this in a rush since I think I misrepresented what I want to do.

When I say "along the lines of warcraft II etc" I mean more like that style of rts using sprites. I don't intend to implement a game nearly that complex, more like just a basic prototype.

My goal would be some thing more like a flat textured map with some basic obstacles like trees, a single unit producing structure like a barracks. I'd like to have the units to have health bars, be able to move and attack and die (and possible morph into another unit).

Far off goals would be to implement some basic pathing using a modified version of the dijkstra shortest path algorithm, ranged units with missle attack, etc.

I don't plan to implement any opponents or ai or networking or anything like that.

Comment: One thing you might consider is trying a Turn Based Strategy Game (like one of my fav games - Advance Wars).  I think an RTS engine might be intense esp for only one year of CS.  Do you have AI experience?

Comment: I think that by asking whether or not it is realistic to write such a complex engine in 3 months you've answered your own question.

Comment: "The person who says it cannot be done should not interrupt the person doing it." (Chinese proverb) Don't pay too much attention to people that say something can't be done. Who's to say? We know nothing about you. Try it. Work hard. You might do something amazing.

Comment: I second the turn based game idea. It is easier. And if you design it in a good way, you will be able to make it RTS later simply by making the turns happen automatically and in small increments.

Comment: @Corbin Sure, that's well and good, but setting up someone for incremental successes is usually more productive than counting on them being a CS genius after one year of school.

Comment: @SB - AI experience is unnecessary; for a simple "AI" you can start out with `if distance_to(player) < attack_distance: attack; else: move_toward(player.position)`

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: For someone new to game programming, implementing `move_toward(player.position)` might be challenge enough (path-finding in a dynamic environment isn't easy), let alone creating AI that isn't impossible/trivial to beat.

Comment: Right but nobody said anything about path finding in a dynamic environment.  The simplest AI just moves straight toward the player.  Everything else is just refinements to the process, but to get started, moving in a straight line is better than doing nothing.  *In other words,* one should start by doing the simplest possible thing, then changing those things that need to be changed to make it better.  Starting out with "ok, time to sit down and do pathfinding in a dynamic environment" is not the path to success.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: I guess I won't argue details much more over a theoretical game that someone else is making :)  You're saying that if he lowers his requirements then he can reasonably expect success, and I agree with that.

Comment: Not exactly, I suggest only that he start with "simple" and iterate toward "complex."  It is a much easier path to take, since (esp. with personal projects) it can get demoralizing to have nothing working for long periods of time.

Comment: @avatarX: End up getting a game running?  My best is a tetris clone, so no pressure to impress!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I'm thinking along the lines of starcraft I, warcraft II or even command and conquer

Make sure you purge your mind of matching the full scope of any of those.  They took large teams of developers multiple years to make, with multi-million dollar budgets, so you can't even hope to approach those.  They're called AAA for a reason.  That being said, there's no reason you can't very minimally ape their design, or make a tiny game in their genre, assuming you have previous experience making small games.

A sub-genre of RTS that might be doable in that amount of time is a [Tower Defense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_defense) game.  Plants vs Zombies is a good example.  The reason I suggest this sub-genre is that you can avoid implementing any sort of AI or path-finding, which are notoriously difficult to get working, and I think technically impossible to implement "perfectly", especially with a limited CPU budget.

Make sure to reign in your scope.  Favor a "complete" game over new features, because you can then call it "done" at any time.  Get your game playable ASAP, and don't sweat the polish or details until you have to.  Add one enemy type and one type of player unit (with only one ability, if you were thinking of implementing multiple abilities per unit).  Make a title screen, menus (even if the menu is just "click screen to play"), game over screen, level complete or stat screens, cross-level player statistics, etc.  Once you have all that ironed out, spend equal time adding new features and polishing the gameplay/graphics/bugs.

Once you have a playable, "complete" game ready (no matter how small in scope), find a real artist to do graphics for you.  A shiny game always draws an audience, no matter how simple the gameplay.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn, you have a good point. I'm actually thinking of something even more simple than that, but extending it into some sort of tower defense would be an excellent idea once I have something playable.

Answer (score 6):

It is very unrealistic to think you could implement a 2D RTS engine anywhere even close to the complexity in those kind of games. You could maybe get something very rough if you were experienced, but with only one year I think it's doubtful.

I can't help but feel like it would be much better for you if you used an existing engine or framework and built off of it.  Like you said, working with other code would probably be a good learning experience as well. It would allow you to experiment without getting bogged down in having to do everything.

Answer (score 5):

Keep it simple or you will simply drown in complexity before getting around to have anything playable.    Since you have not tried it before, you will have a lot of nuts to crack and you don't know how long they will take.

Also remember that report writing and documentation takes time too.

The idea is good, and I think you can pull off a whole game if you find good building blocks.  I would suggest discussing this with your teacher to hear what is acceptable for you to use.  Would it e.g. be ok to do a game on an open source engine if you add some non-trivial functionality?

Update:  Seems to be several engines available from Java at http://www.devmaster.net/engines/list.php?fid=6&sid=1

Comment: Real game developers leave writing reports and documentation until after testing.  That is, we let the users do all of that.  :)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang just noticed that your profile mentions that you are a game developer.  Do you have any experiences to share about writing games in Java?

Comment: Not in a forum like this, and especially not in the comments on an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would make sense to look at some existing efforts to get a feel for the scope of what you are looking at.  These should give you some ideas or even code to build on:

http://www.duncanjauncey.com/btinternet/old/javagame/game.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Java_Game_Library

http://www.ardor3d.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMonkeyEngine

It would be a lot for me to bite off (from scratch) in the time given that is for sure.  That is about all I can say.

**EDIT:** I thought maybe [JOGRE](http://jogre.sourceforge.net/main.htm) was not what you are looking for.  Then I thought about it and it seems like it would have all the right kinds of plumbing for what you are trying to do.

**EDIT AGAIN:** After my answer, one of the related questions links on the side seemed relevant: [Java Game Programming: JOGL vs LWJGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987579/java-game-programming-jogl-vs-lwjgl)

Comment: Thanks Justin, I think duncanjaunceys game will provide a good base to create a 2d RTS

Answer (score 3):

People often forget, that creating games is MUCH MORE than just coding the technique thing. Its about content creation, game design, sound and music, the "fun factor". If you make heavy use of existent APIs or engines, it will be possible, but writing it from scratch with no experience in 3 month is like asking yourself if you can code 100,000 LOC in this time which means 1111 LOC per day. This might be possible, but not if you have to desing and think, and just having the code makes no game.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it gives you any hope at all, my team and I are currently working on an RTS game called "The Genesis Project". We call ourselves MotherBoard Games, or MBG for short. If you would like, I am always looking for more coders. You can email me at mpmn5891@gmail.com, I can give you some advice and tips form my 6 year experience, 2 of which have been spent making this game (to give you a scope)