# Good idea to start game development using open source java game engines?

Tags: java, open-source, game-engine

I have followed tutorials where they show you how to make your own animation class and sound class as well as the basics but I was wondering if it would be beneficial if I were to just use an open source java game engine like jMonkey or the Lightweight Java Game Library, instead of coding my own game engine from scratch? What are you thoughts on this?

Comment: try posting your comment on the GameDev Stack Exchange>
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if it would be beneficial

Beneficial to whom?  Are you trying to learn, or to make a game with a group of people?

Is your goal to learn how games engines work, or make a game?  Both will give you knowledge you wouldn't get otherwise, and neither is the complete story.

Learning how to create your own engine is useful, and learning how other people build game engines is also useful.  Using an existing engine will get you one step closer to making a large game.

Neither choice will really hinder you much from making a small 2D game, as long as you're picking a 2D engine.  If you try to make a 2D game in a 3D engine, that will take quite a bit more time to learn, as 3D adds another level of complexity.

Comment: I was thinking I could just learn how to make a java game engine first as that would make game development easier for me down the line because I don't need to code from scratch everytime I make a game.

Comment: @user1048606: Coding an engine *is* coding from scratch.  If you use a pre-existing engine you never have to code from scratch...

Comment: @user1048606: [A related question that I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711487/java-real-time-strategy-game-development/3711744#3711744).  As for coding an engine, this is hard to do without putting in features you don't need.  Plus it is much easier to design something if you've already seen several examples.  You can find out what you like to work with, and what you don't like, and it will be way faster to design your own engine if you have a user (game logic programmer) mindset rather than a low-level mechanics mindset.

Answer (score 2):

LWJGL is an excellent platform to use, not because it makes your whole engine for you, but because it provides great interfaces into libraries such as OpenGL and OpenAL.

However, it really depends on what kind of game you're making and with what complexity. Since it seems this is a hobby type project, it's probably good to use a middleware layer, however make sure that you still understand what it's doing.

Note that jMonkey and LWJGL are fairly different, since jMonkey **is** actually a full game engine for the most part.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what middleware is? I am hoping to start small by making a simple tetris game at first then eventually I hope to expand and make a simcity type game.

Comment: In that case, don't bother with anything like jMonkey or LWJGL, those are mainly meant for 3D games. Just use the built in Java2D and draw to a canvas etc.

Comment: And middleware in this case is something like LWJGL that lies in the middle of the game code and the original interfaces, providing some sort of abstraction.